# How to force models to take all the input variables in WEKA?

Tags: input, weka, pruning

I am using REPTree model in WEKA. My data has three input variables. Even setting up unpruned as TRUE, REPTree is only taking two input variables. How to force the model to take all the input variables? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithms that learn a decision tree will in general take only a subset of the features. This is because some features do not really carry any information with respect to the classes that you want to distinguish. That is, if for example the feature values are the same for all the examples, then there is no point in including it in a classifier as it does not add any information.

The algorithms that induce decision trees (including REPTree) are designed to pick only the most informative features. Unless you absolutely know what you're doing and have a specific reason for wanting to include all features, you should trust what the algorithm is doing.

Comment: Thank you. However, I would like to see its predictions by adding all the input variables that I am thing are important. Please let me know how to do that in WEKA.

Comment: You can't force the model to take all features into account. However, you could try passing in only the features you think are important.